# How to solve a limit with an exponential: $\lim_{x \to 0^+}e^{(-1/x)}\ln(1/x^2)$?

Tags: limits, exponential-function

So I have this limit of $x$ tending to $0^+$. Of:
$$
e^{(-1/x)}\ln(1/x^2)
$$
I know that I can solve this by using subsitution, thus substituting $1/x$ with $u$, but I really don't seem to grasp the concept, and thus the method in order to solve the system.

I also know that I can solve it using L'Hospital's rule, even if it may seem more difficult, but could I do this: could I convert the function into a fraction and then take the derivative of the numerator and the derivative of the denominator? Could you please show me some steps? Thanks!

I would be really, really useful if you could show me both types of ways on how to solve this limit. (If I had to choose, I would prefer some steps regarding the use of L'Hospital's rule)

Comment: Please see our [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help), esp. [Help Center > Our model > How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1):

> $$
> e^{-1/x}\ln(1/x^2)
> $$
>   but could I do this: could I convert the function into a fraction and then take the derivative of the numerator and the derivative of the denominator?

Sure and thanks to the laws of exponents, it is easily turned into a fraction:
$$e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\ln\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{\ln\frac{1}{x^2}}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$

> (If I had to choose, I would prefer some steps regarding the use of L'Hospital's rule)

Both numerator and denominator now tend to $\infty$ for $x \to 0^+$ so you can apply l'Hôpital's rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln\frac{1}{x^2}}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\left(\ln\frac{1}{x^2}\right)'}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)'}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\frac{-2}{x}}{-x^{-2}e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( 2\,x\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\right)=\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH . Really . Only one thing i didn't quite grasp. How can  e^(-1/x) be re-written as in order to arrive to the first thing you wrote down ?

Comment: That's one of the common laws of exponents (you should know/memorize): $a^{-b}=\frac{1}{a^b}$; apply here with $a=e$ as base and exponent $b=\frac{1}{x}$ to get $e^{-1/x}=\frac{1}{e^{1/x}}$.

Comment: Thanks ... last thing, sorry to annoy you , what about the ln ?? originally , would it be just ln/1 ? so that when i multiply out with the e i get what you wrote

Comment: $\ Lim_{x → 0^+} e^{-1/x}\ln {1}{x^2}= \ Lim_{x → 0^+} \frac{\ln {1}{x^2}}{e^{1/x}}= 0$

because $\ Lim_{x → 0^+}e^{1/x}= ∞$

Comment: @MichaelMorello I don't understand what you mean with that last question. What is "ln/1"...?

Comment: Nothing sorry neever mind, i understood perfectly. But then again the answer would be infinity ?

Comment: No, you should find $0$ for $x\to 0^+$; you would get $+\infty$ for $x\to 0^-$ though. In $2\,x\,e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ both factors tend to $0$ for $x\to 0^+$...!

Comment: The concept i didn't really grasp is the fact of numerator and denomiantor tending to infinity . Does this imply that i can use l'hopital rule when ? only when the num and denom tend to ininifty?

Comment: So i would just plug in the zero...?

Comment: Im kind of confused...

Comment: Comments aren't the best place for discussions; it may be better to include additional but related questions to your original post or open a new question. You can apply l'Hôpital's rule if the numerator and denominator **both** tend to either 0, or $\pm\infty$.

Comment: Perfect. so the last step would just be to plug in 0?

Comment: It's not really just "plugging in" since you can't evaluate $\tfrac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$, but you can say that $e^{-1/x}$ tends to $0$ for $x\to 0^+$; this is something you should know as a property of the exponential function ($e^x$ has a horizontal asymptote at height $0$ for $x\to -\infty$).